# How to easily make custom Stream class in Java (like with Ruby Enumerable)

Tags: java

In Ruby, if you mix the `Enumerable` module into your own custom collection class, you only have to implement the `each` method, and all the methods of `Enumerable` (`map`, `select`, `reduce`, etc.) become available on your own class.

In Java 8, does the class library have an interface or abstract class that you can inherit from, such that you only have to override a single method to create your own `Stream` class?  I could generate a `Stream<T>` instance by using `Stream<T>.generate` or `Stream.Builder<T>`, but I would like to be able create a custom `Stream` class (without having to do a lot of work).

Comment: `Stream` is already an interface.  You can create a class to implement that interface.  I'm a bit unclear as to what your confusion is though; you can implement that interface in any way you wish.  It's never going to be like Ruby though, since Ruby's way of going about mixins/modules is different than interfaces.

Comment: What I had in mind was some abstract class implementing `Stream` that would maybe require you just to override a single method (like `each` in Ruby) in order to make your own custom `Stream` class.  But that doesn't seem to a pattern that the stream library is designed to support.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think inheritance isn't the approach `Stream`s are designed for in Java. So you'd rather to implement the `Spliterator` interface and create a stream upon your data presented via such a Spliterator and then build your stream via

```
StreamSupport.stream(data, parallel);
```

This way you can provide pretty specific forms of data as a stream without copying all the data into the stream as it's necessary with the methods you mentioned. But if you really need to overwrite some of the stream behaviors thing get pretty weird. So hopefully that's not actually what you need.